# Repeat each elements based on a list of values

Tags: python, list

Is there a Python builtin that repeats each element of a list based on the corresponding value in another list? For example `A` in list `x` position 0 is repeated 2 times because of the value `2` at position 0 in the list `y`.

```
>>> x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> y = [2, 1, 3]
>>> f(x, y)
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Or to put it another way, what is the fastest way to achieve this operation?

Comment: I performed a `%timeit` on the answers of A.J. (list comprehension), Randy C.(itertools), and mkHun and Paul Rooney (list extend) using `f(['A', 'B', 'C'], [20000, 10, 3])`. List extension was fastest at 155 microsseconds, then list comprehension at 301 us and the slowest was itertools at 1.3ms.

Comment: **edit** list comp is slowest not itertools. List extension < itertools < list comp. Hope I clarified the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be the following

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
y = [2, 1, 3]

s = []
for a, b in zip(x, y):
    s.extend([a] * b)

print(s)
```

result

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Comment: I did a `%timeit` and this was the fastest

Comment: `list(''.join([a*b for a,b in zip(x,y)]))` is almost as fast (162 us) but not faster than Paul Rooney's code (155 us) after 10000 iterations

Answer (score 4):

Just use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> y = [2, 1, 3]
>>> [x[i] for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(y[i])]
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
>>>
```

Comment: Alternatively `[n for n, c in zip(x, y) for _ in range(c)]`

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*[[a] * b for a, b in zip(x, y)]))
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

There is `itertools.repeat` as well, but that ends up being uglier for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']
y = [2, 1, 3]
newarray = []
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    newarray.extend(x[i] * y[i])

print newarray
```