# Iterating through groups in List A and multiplying by item in List B

Tags: python

I want to multiply each of the first 9 items in `listA` by the first item in `ListB`, then the next group of 9 items in `ListA` by the second item in `listB`, and so on through `ListA`.  So far, I have the following but it does not work -- `newlist` contains only one group of 9 items (it should be 12 groups of 9 items).

```
k = 0
n = 0
for i, factor in enumerate(listA[k:k+9]):
    newlist.append(factor * ListB[n])
    k += 9
    n += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: list comprehension with nested for loop**

This solution uses a nested `for` loop within a list comprehension. `itertools.islice` allows us to build the result without forming intermediary lists.

```
from itertools import islice

A = list(range(1, 28))
B = list(range(1, 4))

res = [i*B[k] for k in range(int(len(A)/9)) for i in islice(A, k*9, (k+1)*9)]

print(res)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36,
 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81]
```

**Option 2: list comprehension with zip + itertools.repeat**

`itertools.repeat` repeats an element *n* times. Together with `zip` and `itertools.chain`, you can manipulate this to the desired iterable.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

B_repeated = chain.from_iterable(zip(*repeat(B, 9)))
res = [i*j for i, j in zip(A, B_repeated)]
```

**Option 3: numpy.repeat**

If you can use a 3rd party library, `numpy` offers a trivial solution:

```
import numpy as np

res = A * np.repeat(B, 9)

array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
       20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36,
       57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of chopping up `ListA`, you can expand `ListB` by a factor of 9. If you use a generator expression to do this, you won't even need extra storage. The expansion can be done using the double comprehension in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38758795/2988730:

```
genB = (x for x in ListB for _ in range(9))
newlist = [n * x for n, x in zip(ListA, genB)]
```

You can combine this into a one-liner if you like. This solution is nice because it requires neither imports nor indexing, just basic iteration. This makes it easier to extend the functionality. So for example if you had an iterable that told you the group size instead of always having 9:

```
genB = (x for x, count in zip(ListB, counts) for _ in range(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the first list on a separate line, then use `zip`:

```
a = list(range(81)) #example data
b = range(1, 10) #example data
new_a = [a[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(a), 9)]
final_results = [[c*j for c in i] for i, j in zip(new_a, b)]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34], [54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78], [108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140], [180, 185, 190, 195, 200, 205, 210, 215, 220], [270, 276, 282, 288, 294, 300, 306, 312, 318], [378, 385, 392, 399, 406, 413, 420, 427, 434], [504, 512, 520, 528, 536, 544, 552, 560, 568], [648, 657, 666, 675, 684, 693, 702, 711, 720]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> General advice: Try using python's inbuilt features like lambda, zip,
>   map, filter, etc. as frequent as possible.

```
>>> a = range(27)
>>> b = range(3)
>>> result = [map(lambda x: x * b[i], a[9*i: 9*(i+1)]) for i in xrange(len(b))]
>>> result
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to multiply each value in list A by a value in list B. For example if the number 1 is in list B, you want to multiply it by each value in list A, such as (1 * 1, 1 *  2 , 1 * 3....) and so on. Then You want to append it to a list called "new_list". Here is an example that can do that:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
new_list = []

for num in list_b:
    for number in list_a:
        new_num = number * num
        new_list.append(new_num)

print(new_list)
```

Here we start with a for loop that iterates through all 12 numbers in list B. It will then iterate through all 9 numbers for list A, and multiply each number in B * A. As you stated, you should get 108 results instead of the output you were getting (9 * 12). We append the output to the new list.

Here is your output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108]
```

Comment: @jpp. I don't think that OP is asking for a modified version of `itertools.product`. Pretty sure this is not right

Answer (score 0):

Another way: make `listB` as long as `listA` with a double list comprehension.

```
listA = list(range(9 * 12))
listB = list(range(9))

res = [a * b for a, b in zip(listA, [b_ for b in listB for b_ in [b] * 12])]
```

To get groups:

```
In [872]: list(zip(*(res[i::9] for i in range(9))))
Out[872]: 
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),
 (18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 48, 50, 52),
 (54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70),
 (108, 111, 114, 117, 120, 123, 126, 129, 132),
 (135, 138, 141, 192, 196, 200, 204, 208, 212),
 (216, 220, 224, 228, 232, 236, 300, 305, 310),
 (315, 320, 325, 330, 335, 340, 345, 350, 355),
 (432, 438, 444, 450, 456, 462, 468, 474, 480),
 (486, 492, 498, 588, 595, 602, 609, 616, 623),
 (630, 637, 644, 651, 658, 665, 768, 776, 784),
 (792, 800, 808, 816, 824, 832, 840, 848, 856)]
```